# list first N rows from Pandas df using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to group a pandas df, and pass the values grouped to a list

```
  df.groupby(['Column1','Column2'])['Column3'].apply(list)
```

This returns all values from column3 in the list.
How can i get the list to include only first N examples only from column3  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexing with lambda function:

```
df.groupby(['Column1','Column2'])['Column3'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[:N])
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(['Column1','Column2'])['Column3'].apply(lambda x: list(x.iloc[:N]))
```

EDIT:

```
df.groupby(['Column1','Column2'])['Column3'].apply(lambda x: list(x.unique()[:N]))
```

Comment: Thanks - any way to make this list top N distinct values?

Comment: @Manny - can you try `df.groupby(['Column1','Column2'])['Column3'].apply(lambda x: list(x.unique()[:N]))` ?